# Linux 4.13 crash when run under xen 4.9

Tags: linux, boot, virtualization, xen

When I start linux-4.13 under Xen hypervisor it fails in early_iounmap procedure at start:
[image: failure photo]

Hardware: Lenovo Thinkpad e330, 8 G RAM

cpuinfo:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 2020M @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x12
cpu MHz     : 2394.697
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4791.95
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 2020M @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x12
cpu MHz     : 2394.697
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4792.28
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Distro: Archlinux

When run this kernel on bare metal, everything OK.

Where I need to see, to find cause of this crash?